# How to deal with empty user inputs in a parametrized query?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, web-applications

Let's say I have the following query template somewhere in my web application :

```
`WHERE UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER('%${NAME}%') AND UPPER(LASTNAME) LIKE UPPER('%${LASTNAME}%')`
```

Now, if the user inputs empty values in the application for one of the fields, will that affect the query result?

And this could be solved via application by breaking down the query and constructing it during execution using ifs, but for some queries this complicates the application code too much.

Is there a way to inherently solve this inside the template? Using only SQL language and not application logic.

And if I don't solve it, if I simply query with the empty inputs, will that affect my performance too much? Does oracle have an intelligence to not query empty inputs?

**Basically** : How bad is it to query something like `NAME LIKE '%%'` ? Will Oracle ignore this part of the query or will it affect performance (I want it to be ignored as this the result of the user not inputting anything in the form)? This is a simple example but there are more complex ones with nested queries.

Its a lazy way to deal with the user not inputting any value in the application form, let's say he leaves the `name` field blank in the form, in this case I want all `name`s in the query without having to construct a new template.

Tagged Javascript as that is the application language.

Comment: To some extent, can't you just try it and see what happens? What do you **want** to happen if they do that? You're effectively not filtering; if `$NAME` is empty, you'll look for all not-null values, as you'll be comparing with `'%%'`. Is that what you want? You're already potentially killing performance with the `UPPER(NAME)`, unless you have function-based indexes.

Comment: @AlexPoole if $NAME is empty I want it to be ignored basically, as the user did not put anything in the form, I have to use UPPER as these are case sensitive fields. But I would like to know if Oracle really ignores it, or I would have to break down the queries and not include the ones to be ignored for better performance.

Comment: Validate the critical parameters before even attempting the query. If something's missing let user know

Comment: Best approach is always make sure your query is what exactly you want it to be so that data returned is predictable. So if there are any parameters which can potentially impact resultset to be, even potentially, incorrect. Must change your query so that you get what exactly is desired. This would mean only run query with parameters which are there and are needed to get a particular set of data as result

Comment: `where name like '%'` is equivalent to `where name is not null` (because it has to have a non-null value in order to be `like` anything).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that is the expected behaviour (user did not input anything in the form), my question is if that will affect performance too much, considering there could be several of these in a query

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be generating raw SQL in the browser anyway, as that risks SQL injection attacks, not to mention failures when `name` is `O'Brian` and the effect on the database's cursor cache.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? That is not a technical term in SQL. Do you want the output to have one less column - to not show the NAME column at all? Or what else? If you want the condition on NAME in the `where` clause to be ignored, you can say `where (NAME is null or .... ) and (LASTNAME is null or ...)` (adjust this for your actual code; `${NAME}` suggests this is pre-processed by another programming language or scripting language before it is "seen" by Oracle SQL).

Comment: @mathguy Let's say its a lazy way to construct the where part of the query, when the user inputs an empty value in the application search form I should not include that part in the final query, but instead I will just leave the empty value.

Comment: Oh - so if the table has names like `John` and `Alice` but the user inputs nothing for that field, you want the NAME column to still be part of the output, but the values in that column are all NULL? That is easy to do, but first please this is the "business requirement" since it seems odd. Normally you would just show the names as they are in the data, not "mask" them with NULL (empty string).

Comment: @mathguy yes, its not the business requirement but the framework I'm using, so if the user inputs nothing for the name field, I want all the names basically. And from the answers I'm seeing my current approach won't work if we have names that are null

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't ever generate SQL straight with user inputs, otherwise you're going to get hacked.  Search for "SQL Injection" - still the method of choice for hackers everywhere.

2) Once you've got bind variables to avoid getting hacked, your SQL statement can be just:

```
where ( :first_name is null or name like :first_name )
and   ( :last_name is null or name like :last_name )
and  ...
```

where the bind variable contains leading and trailing % signs if you choose to do so.  The optimizer will naturally filter out those parameters that were null.

Comment: The problem is that the application framework I'm using only lets me pass the "where" part of the query, so I only have control over a string, can't create bind variables in oracle. So in your case it would translate to `where ('' is null or name like '')` if the user gives no inputs. I'm willing to open a bounty for an answer to my problem.

Comment: Nulls dont work for equality in that sense, so it would be:

`@name is null or name like @name`

Comment: The thing is that null will never be inserted by the user, only an empty string since it is constructed in javascript

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL I use this approach:

```
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @LASTNAME NVARCHAR(100) = '%XYZ%'

select *
from CUSTOMER 
WHERE UPPER(LASTNAME) LIKE case when UPPER(@NAME) is null then UPPER(LASTNAME) else UPPER(@NAME) end
  AND UPPER(FIRSTNAME) LIKE case when UPPER(@LASTNAME) is null then UPPER(FIRSTNAME) else UPPER(@LASTNAME) end
```

and it gives me this result

```
LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME
xyz         xyz
```

Comment: The OP clearly marked this as Oracle, so giving a MS SQL solution is helping no one. In addition, what you propose is correct, but too complicated. Why not `where (name is null or .....) and (lastname is null or ....)`? `case` is the right answer in many situations, but here it is overkill.